# Observable json join on id

Tags: javascript, observable, rxjs6

Let's say I have two REST services :

```
todo.service.ts
user.service.ts
```

Here is the definition of each objects :

```
todo: userId, title, id, completed
user: id, name, email, etc
```

Both my services are returning me Observable with collections of the definition.

```
users: Observable<User[]>
todos: Observable<Todo[]>
```

The final result is to display something like this :

```
todo.title by user.name
```

What is the best way to do it ? Is it to map them to one single object like :

```
todo: id, title, completed, user { id, name, email, etc }
```

Or is there a better way to archieve that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] in the question itself, not only on an external site. Also, "better" and "best" are subjective; what's wrong with the way you have it and what objective criteria will you use to identify which is the best?

Comment: I think you may need to provide additional context of how/when exactly you plan to access these pieces of data. Are you planning to have routing based on something like user id or todo id? You may want to provide how you plan to display this data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of things to be a bit strange about your implementation, so I just changed them and I'll explain.

Inside your services, you should create a function to return the observable instead of doing it in your constructor, that way you can always delay fetching the data, or refresh using the same function. Like so (other service identical changes):

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private API = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.API);
  }
}
```

Then inside the component, create 2 lists that you can manually update using a promise, or subscribe to an observable if it is subject to change.

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  todos:[];
  users:[];

  constructor(
    private todoService: TodoService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
    this.getUsers();
    this.getTodos();
  }

  getTodos() {
    // promise so fetch only once
    this.todoService.getToDos().toPromise().then(todos => {
      this.todos = todos;
    });
  }

  getUsers() {
    // promise so fetch only once
    this.userService.getUsers().toPromise().then(users => {
      this.users = users;
    });
  }

  getUsername(id) {
    if (this.users && this.users.length > 0) {
      return this.users.find(user => {
        return user.id === id;
      }).name;
    }
  }
}
```

And the html:

```
<h3>Users</h3>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }}</li>
</ul>

<h3>Todos</h3>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">{{ todo.title }} ({{ getUsername(todo.userId) }})</li>
</ul>
```

That gives me the following output:

Users

- Leanne Graham
- Ervin Howell
- Clementine Bauch
- Patricia Lebsack
- Chelsey Dietrich
- Mrs. Dennis Schulist
- Kurtis Weissnat
- Nicholas Runolfsdottir V
- Glenna Reichert
- Clementina DuBuque

Todos

- delectus aut autem (Leanne Graham)
- quis ut nam facilis et officia qui (Leanne Graham)
- fugiat veniam minus (Leanne Graham)
- et porro tempora (Leanne Graham)
- laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum (Leanne Graham)
- qui ullam ratione quibusdam voluptatem quia omnis (Leanne Graham)
- illo expedita consequatur quia in (Leanne Graham)

etc.

> What is the best way to do it ? Is it to map them to one single object like

I would not do that, because 1 list can be changed while the other remains the same, having the option to maintain them individually is an advantage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That what I am doing now in my projects but I want to move to rxjs for some reasons.

EDIT: So, I need to use Observable with | async in my template etc

Comment: @Leix this implementation also uses observables that are async, the syntax is just different. you can read about it here: https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794. Also, that is not part of your question right now. So if you update the question with more details, or post a new question, we can help u further